# Can't install only "psych" in R (other packages work normal)

Tags: r, install.packages, psych

**I downloaded R and Rstudio on my windows and everything work normally, except "psych". When I installed other packages there was no problem, but when I tried to install "psych" Rstudio returns:**

*> install.packages("psych")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
dependency ‘mnormt’ is not available
There is a binary version available but the source
version is later:
binary source needs_compilation
psych 1.9.12.31  2.0.7             FALSE
installing the source package ‘psych’
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/psych_2.0.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1743492 bytes (1.7 MB)
downloaded 1.7 MB*

*ERROR: dependency 'mnormt' is not available for package 'psych'

- removing 'C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/psych'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘psych’ had non-zero exit status
  The downloaded source packages are in
  ‘C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0uWPga\downloaded_packages’*

**I downloaded Rtools, installed it into 3.6.(as required) butr it's still not working.
When I tried to install "mnormt" it returns:**

> install.packages("mnormt")
> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘mnormt’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

If anyone knows how can I install "psych" I would really appreciate to help me.

Comment: Hi Katja, would you be open to upgrade R to its latest version? That would likely solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even noticed that my R is not the last version, I just checked RStudio.